# History JS/.htaccess - Rewrite all to index but preserve path

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, reactjs, history.js

I'm building a an app in React and due to the layout/ state of the app i'm unable to use React Router and therefore using history JS to manage site navigation. In my outer most container i've setup the following code to manage navigation:

```
handlePageChange = (event) => {

    //stop default page change
    event.preventDefault();

    const history = createHistory()

    if(typeof(event.target.tagName) === "undefined") {
        var newURL = window.location.pathname;
    } else {
        var newURL = event.target.getAttribute('href');
        history.push(newURL)
    }

    this.setState({
        activePage:newURL.replace('/','')
    })

    setTimeout(function(){
        this.setState({
            sideNavState:""
        })            
    }.bind(this),300)

}
```

The above code works fine for navigating pages but I have an issue when it comes to accessing the links directly. For example if I try to access mysite.com/page1 I get a requested URL not found on this server because I haven't setup any pages as they are controlled by the apps state.

I want all pages (mysite.com/page1, mysite.com/page2 etc..) to point to the same index.html file which lies in the root so what would be the correct approach for this? I've used the below .htaccess rewrite conditions but am a bit lost with the syntax involved so have not been able to get it to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ index.html?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also, am I using the correct approach here for the page navigation i'm trying to achieve? Worth noting that I only get this issue when I host my app and on localhost it behaves how I want it to.

Thanks!

Comment: Unsure of the right approach in htaccess (someone else will surely answer) but you want to wildcard everything back to your index.html so that the frontend can handle all routing.

Comment: This is a very muddled question. I'm really unsure what your asking about? Is it react, php, htaccess, what? What exactly do you want and what exactly isn't working? I think this may be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your *asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.*

Comment: Yes Samhh that's correct, I wanted be able to preserve the path as well though...

Comment: The question is in regards to .htaccess @Liam but I was also asking if a .htaccess rewrite is the correct approach here

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was after:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.html?id=$1 [QSA]
```

This is thanks to this link [here](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)

Now the document stops the page looking for the subdirectory root, rewrites back to the site root with the appended path